# How can I use a pointer to a pointer to a string object and use the pointer to the pointer to call size() member function of the string object

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I need some advice on how to approach this problem. I need to assign a pointer to a pointer that points to a string object that contains the word. I wish to use the pointer to the pointer to call the size() member function of that string object. Any help on solving this problem or how I can approach this problem with an example would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `*` once per indirection level, like in the declaration of the variable.

```
std::string s = "tjena"; // A string
std::string *sp = &s; // A pointer to a string
std::string **spp = &sp; // A pointer to a pointer to a string
(**spp).size(); // Call it like this
(*spp)->size(); // Or like this
(*sp).size(); // Or like this
sp->size(); // Or like this
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply dereference the pointers twice to reach the actual string object.

Given:

```
string word = ...;
string *pword = &word;
string **ppword = &pword;
```

You can do this:

```
int size = (*ppword)->size();
```

Or this:

```
int size = (**ppword).size();
```